# Infinite Loop Error When Loading xib in Subview of UIScrollView

Tags: ios6, uitableview, uiscrollview, xib

I have created a custom subclass of a UIView with a xib (DHSwipeView) and am attempting to programmatically add multiple instances of this subclass to a UIScrollView that is contained within a custom UITableViewCell (working off the github project uploaded here: https://github.com/derrh/SwipeAwayCell/blob/master/SwipeAwayCell/DHSwipeAwayCell.h).  The ultimate goal is to have a UITableView with entries that can be scrolled through horizontally, with each page in the UIScrollView representing an instance of my custom UIView subclass.

When I initialize the custom UIView and add programmatic formatting (adding labels, etc.), my program works fine.  However, when the UIScrollView inits the custom UIView and then loads the xib, it enters into an infinite loop.

My container view code for the UIScrollView is below:

```
#import "DHSwipeAwayCell.h"
#import "DHSwipe.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation DHSwipeAwayCell

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]
                         initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                  self.frame.size.width,
                                                  self.frame.size.height)];
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [self.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];;

    NSInteger numberOfViews = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {

        CGFloat myOrigin = i * self.frame.size.width;

        //create the sub view and allocate memory
        DHSwipe *myView = [[DHSwipe alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myOrigin, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

        self.scrollView.delegate = self;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:myView];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width * numberOfViews,
                                           self.frame.size.height);

    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 2, 0);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

    [self addSubview:self.scrollView];
    NSLog(@"Finish");

}

@end
```

My custom UIView subclass is below:

```
#import "DHSwipe.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation DHSwipe

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
//When I include the following commands, the UIScrollView program goes into an infinite loop   
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DHSwipeView" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        self.frame = frame; 
        self.cellTitle.text = @"Good!";
        NSLog(@"%@", self.cellTitle);

//This formatting works
        UIView *roundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, self.frame.size.height - 10)];
        roundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        roundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        roundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
        roundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
        roundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        [self addSubview:roundedCornerView];
        [self sendSubviewToBack:roundedCornerView];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Everything seems to be connected fine in IB, and the NSLog command that prints the UILabel subclass shows that the label exists with the correct text.  However, when I check the logs, the UIScrollView completes its loop (printing "Finish") through the instantiation of the subclass UIViews, but then seems to go back and infinitely loop through them all again.  Is there something I am missing that is related to the loading of this custom xib?

Comment: What happens if you remove the line self = [nib objectAtIndex:0]; ?

Comment: If there's no line to set which object in the nib corresponds to the custom view, then nothing gets loaded.  I was under the impression that the NSBundle call and setting self to object at index 0 were standard for nib loading, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Aren't you redefining self though ... ? Have you tried single stepping through it ?
Surely, you need an initWithNib not initWithFrame .. ? 
See my answer ..?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

   if (self) {
       // blah
   }


   return self;

}
```

Then call this init and pass your xib through instead ?